# Query on Bean instantiation in spring and static factory

Tags: java, spring

I have query on bean  instantiation in spring.

According to the Spring Reference document, in the section 'Instantiating beans", it is mentioned that

" container itself directly creates the bean by calling its constructor reflectively, somewhat equivalent to Java code using the new operator " .

This implies that Spring container uses reflection to create beans.How ever in few scenarios, container  also uses static factory method on a class to create a bean. The only case I knew container use static factory method is "WHEN THE CONSTRUCTOR IS PRIVATE".

So my doubt is, since container uses Reflection to create objects, it should be able create objects of classes  of even private constructor as well.Why should container rely on static factory method ?
Or are there any other uses of calling static factory method to create beans ?

Thanks in advance. If there is any fundamental understanding required for me, kindly suggest so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you are right Spring can invoke private constructor if you provide right arguments while defining the bean in configuration. But on question that comes to my mind is why would you do that if that bean is not meant to be instantiated?

It would be the case only say when you have helper class with static method or singleton etc. So it wont make sense to instantiate those classes.

But in your case, it's factory and you might be getting the object back by calling static method (accessing Static method/field doesn't necessarily need Object to access field/method) say getShape and you might be getting different shape based on parameter's that you might supply.

Answer (score 0):

We sometimes need to use a class which was not designed for Spring and need to be instantiated via static factory method and Spring provides us with such possibility.